# How to connect flask to ajax (retrieve data without having to reload entire page)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

**Goal** : My code attempts to carry out the following steps :  the first works, but I can't figure out how to make the POST ajax call in the second step work:

1. When I upload an image, it is displayed on the page.
2. When I click the `Get prediction` button, I want the result of the `predict()` function to be displayed in the `<p>` tag while the image remains on the page (i.e, without reloading the page)

I've read that AJAX is used to update parts of a web page without having to reload the entire page, but I can't seem to get it to work (Answers to a similar question did not work)

**What the following code is doing instead** : when I click `Get prediction` button, the alert is displayed (used for debugging purposes) but the result of the `predict()` function is displayed in a new page.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # the page that is rendered first
    return render_template('hello2_without_ajax.html')


@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        img_path = f"static/uploads/{file.filename}"
        prediction = generate_prediction(img_path)

        return str(prediction)
```

html code :

```
<form id="upload-file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input onchange="readURL(this)" type="file" id="upload" name='file' style="display: none;" autocomplete="off" required>
  <img id="blah" />

  <button id="submit_btn" onclick="$('#upload').click();">Upload image</button>

  <button id="result" type="submit">Get prediction</button>

  <p id="msg" style=" margin-left: 200px;"> </p>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#result").on("click", function(e) {

    var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);

    alert(form_data)

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/',
      data: form_data,
      timeout: 600000,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,

      success: function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS !!: ", data);

        $('#msg').text(' Prediction is:  ' + data);
      },

      error: function(e) {
        console.log('Failuuuuure!!')
        console.log("ERROR : ", e.responseText);
        alert("ERROR : " + e.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in Ajax you are making a call to `'/'` url which directs you to the index route not the predict route, so you need to add change the url for predict route

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def predict():
```

And in Ajax you need to call /predict:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/predict',
```

In your html you need to add `type="button"` attribute for both buttons not  not `type="submit"`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion and I got a Flask Error: "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL”, I attempted to remove the error by adding methods to the `index()` function, but it simply reloaded the page.

I notice that the `predict()` function is not being executed until I add `type="submit”` to the button.

Comment: Try to remove `method='post'` from the form tag